# Copy files to iPhone System Folders

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I am developing for Jailbroken iPhone. I need to write(copy) a file to iPhone System Folders (/Library/LaunchDaemons) to which only ROOT has write access. How can i write a file to such folders through my Code. I know i can use NSFileManager's copyItemAtPath:toPath method to copy the file, but i cant write as i dont have permission to write on such folders.

Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i have found the answer to this question. In order to write to System folders you need to have permission to write on that folder. My app had a Daemon attached to it, so i had to copy that Daemon to /System/Library/LaunchDaemons to make that Daemon work. So as i am developing for JB iphone and people are going to install my app using Cydia, why not to make Cydia install the files of my app to proper locations. I made Cydia to copy the Daemon file into /System/Library/LaunchDaemon folder. Now the question is how Cydia will know where to paste the files. Answer is simple, just make the proper folders in .deb file and cydia will paste the files located in the folders inside the .deb file.

For Example if you have a Daemon and you want Cydia to paste it to /System/Library/LaunchDaemons , make the file structure like this before making a .deb

```
+- MyApp
   +- Applications
      +Myapp.app
   +-DEBIAN
    -control
   +-System
     +-Library
       +-LaunchDaemons
         +- com.myLaunchDaemon.plist
```

Cydia while installing your app will paste the com.myLaunchDaemon.plist file in System/Library/LaunchDaemons, reboot and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your app could run as root or setuid root.

Comment: and how to do that? Any examples on how to do this??

Comment: And expect to hear later that your program is being used for exploits on iPhones where it is installed.

Comment: Good point. I heard that standard issue iPhoneOS has no setuid apps, that the iphone way is via launchd + a daemon.

Comment: thanks for the replies. If i cant run my app as root, then what is the best way to write on private directories?
Remember i am developing for JB iphones.

Comment: Create a small privileged daemon that does it for you.

Comment: I have created a Daemon which i need to paste into /Library/LaunchDaemons/ , but since /Library/LaunchDaemons dont have a write access for my app, so i cant write to that folder. This is what i want to do but dont know how to. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Since you're working on JB you've got a bit more flexibility. You could require the user to install your app as root, via a script.

Comment: I want my app to be efficient. Asking user to SSH and then place the Daemon into /Library/LaunchDaemons will make user feel a little uncomfortable. Also all the users dont know about running scripts or SSH. The app should do such stuff on its own

Comment: How is your app distributed and installed? BTW if you're on JB, most root passwords are "alpine", so just sudo and install the file yourself. Voilà!

Comment: App is gonna install through Cydia. And most of the JB phones these days have their default password changed, because of the security threats.

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of install hook you can use in Cydia.

Comment: I don't know. I haven't released any apps through Cydia, but maybe it's got a package manager that lets you do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running your whole app as root it is much better design to have a small helper tool that will install the files. Then only that helper tool has to run as root.

For more info about SUID binaries check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid as a good start.

Comment: If you do this you should make the helper application *very* limited.  It shouldn't be able to write any file to any directory or someone will figure out how to exploit it to take over iPhones where your program is installed.